# Function Exceptions in Pulsar (PUB-SUB)

Tags: publish-subscribe, apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

I need help with Pulsar Function Exceptions, what are User Function Exceptions and what will happen if its Rate/Count is high and also what could be the cause of high Rate/Count.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to this question? Exceptions can occur in multiple locations with Pulsar functions. There are the traditional checked exceptions that occur inside the code and then there are unchecked exceptions that can occur in the Pulsar function framework code.

Comment: Well thanks a lot for your reply. Seems that the problem is solved ( not permanent I think). Can you provide some reference to "pulsar function framework", it could an error or solution or any other reading material just to understand it better I think.. that would be really helpful.

Comment: What I mean by "pulsar function framework", is the underlying code inside Pulsar that is responsible for delivering and acknowledging the messages that are provide to your function on every invocation. Exceptions at that level are don't appear in the functions log files. Consider a message that has compressed content. When it is delivered to the function it must first be decompressed so it can be provided as the expected type. Now if that decompressed message size exceeds the maximum message size in Pulsar an unchecked exception occurs and the message is not delivered to the function.

Comment: The problem was with ignite due which it throws an exception but again thanks for clearing it out.